# Is it possible for a DynamoDB read to return state that is older than the state returned by a previous read?

Tags: database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, consistency, eventual-consistency

Let's say there is a DynamoDB key with a value of `0`, and there is a process that repeatably reads from this key using eventually consistent reads.  While these reads are occurring, a second process sets the value of that key to `1`.

Is it ever possible for the read process to ever read a `0` *after* it first reads a `1`?  Is it possible in DynamoDB's eventual consistency model for a client to successfully read a key's fully up-to-date value, but then read a stale value on a subsequent request?

Eventually, the write will be fully propagated and the read process will only read `1` values, but I'm unsure if it's possible for the reads to go 'backward in time' while the propagation is occuring.

Answer (score 3):

The property you are looking for is known as **monotonic reads**, see for example the definition in https://jepsen.io/consistency/models/monotonic-reads.

Obviously, DynamoDB's **strongly consistent** read (`ConsistentRead`=true) is also monotonic, but you rightly asked about DynamoDB's **eventually consistent** read mode.

@Charles in his response gave a link, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvBR71D0nAQ&t=706s, to a nice official official talk by Amazon on how eventually-consistent reads work. The talk explains that DynamoDB replicates written data to three copies, but a write completes when two out of three (including one designated as the "leader") of the copies were updated. It is possible that the third copy will take some time (usually a very short time to get updated).

The video goes on to explain that an *eventually consistent* read goes to one of the three replicas *at random*.

So in that short amount of time where the third replica has old data, a request might randomly go to one of the updated nodes and return new data, and then another request slightly later might go by random to the non-updated replica and return old data. This means that the "monotonic read" guarantee is not provided.

To summarize, I believe that DynamoDB does **not** provide the monotonic read guarantee if you use **eventually consistent** reads. You can use strongly-consistent reads to get it, of course.

Unfortunately I can't find an official document which claims this. It would also be nice to test this in practice, similar to how he paper http://www.aifb.kit.edu/images/1/17/How_soon_is_eventual.pdf tested whether Amazon S3 (not DynamoDB) guaranteed monotonic reads, and discovered that it did not by actually seeing monotonic-read violations.

One of the implementation details which may make it hard to see these monotonic-read violations in practice is how Amazon handles requests from the same process (which you said is your case). When the same process sends several requests in sequence, it *may* (but also may not...) may use the same HTTP connections to do so, and Amazon's internal load balancers *may* (but also may not) decide to send those requests to the same backend replica - despite the statement in the video that each request is sent to a random replica. If this happens, it may be hard to see monotonic read violations in practice - but it may still happen if the load balancer changes its mind, or the client library opens another connection, and so on, so you still can't trust the monotonic read property to hold.

Comment: great points.  I should be more careful with answers written after a long day. :)  I've updated my answer to touch upon some of those same implementation details you wonder about.  I'd be really curious about what you think of the idea that DAX would provide monotonic reads.

Comment: Beautiful summary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. Requests are stateless so a second read from the same client is just as likely as any other request to see slightly stale data. If that’s an issue, choose strong consistency.

Comment: I don't believe this is the case, do you have a source?

Comment: "Eventual Consistency: When you read data from a DynamoDB table, the response might not reflect the results of a recently completed write operation. The response might include some stale data. If you repeat your read request after a short time, the response should return the latest data." https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html There's no "except repeated requests from the same client get special treatment" clause.

Answer (score 0):

You will (probably) not ever get the old data after getting the new data..

First off, there's no warning in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html) about repeated reads returning stale data, just that a read after a write may return stale data.

> **Eventually Consistent Reads**
>
> When you read data from a DynamoDB table, the response might not
> reflect the results of a recently completed write operation. The
> response might include some stale data. If you repeat your read
> request after a short time, the response should return the latest
> data.

But more importantly, every item in DDB is stored in three storage nodes. A write to DDB doesn't return a 200 - Success until that data is written to 2 of 3 storage nodes.  Thus, it's only if your read is serviced by the third node, that you'd see stale data.  Once that third node is updated, every node has the latest.

See [Amazon DynamoDB Under the Hood](https://youtu.be/yvBR71D0nAQ?t=706)

**EDIT**
@Nadav's answer points that it's at least theoretically possible; AWS certainly doesn't seem to guarantee monotonic reads.  But I believe the reality depends on your application architecture.

Most languages, [nodejs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-reusing-connections.html) being an exception, will use persistent HTTP/HTTPS connections by default to the DDB request router.  Especially given how expensive it is to open a TLS connection.  I suspect though can't find any documents confirming it that there's at least some level of stickiness from the request router to a storage node.  @Nadav discusses this possibility.  But only AWS knows for sure and they haven't said.

Assuming that belief is correct

- `curl` in a shell script loop - more likely to see the old data again
- loop in C# using a single connection - less likely

The other thing to consider is that in the normal course of things, the third storage node in "only milliseconds behind".

Ironically, if the request router truly picks a storage node at random, a non-persistent connection is then less likely to see old data again given the extra time it takes to establish the connection.

If you absolutely need monotonic reads, then you'd need to use strongly consistent reads.

Another option ***might*** be to stick DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX) in front of your DDB.  Especially if you're retrieving the key with GetItem(). As I read [how it works](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DAX.concepts.html) it does seem to imply monotonic reads, especially if you've written-through DAX.  Though it does not come right out an say so.  Even if you've written around DAX, reading from it should still be monotonic, it's just there will be more latency until you start seeing the new data.

Comment: Charles, I believe this answer is wrong. I wrote my own answer based on the same source that you used to explain why. I think you missed the issue of what happens if one of your reads is serviced by the first node (so sees **new** data), and then a short amount of time later, another one of your reads is serviced by the third node (se sees **old** data). This is exactly what the questioner was worried about: You see new data in one read, and then a later read sees again the old data.